# Find image tags in JQuery that are NOT wrapped in certain HTML

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

So I had another question on here of how I could find all the validation images on the view using JQuery. This worked, but it turns out that when we update our fields on the page, we don't completely remove the validation images, we wrap them in this:

```
<span style="display: none;" validationfor="ResetDayComponent.ResetBusinessDayConvention">
</span>
```

So instead of using this JQuery:

```
if ( $('img.validation').length ) // validation errors exist
{
    alert("errors");
    return;
}
```

How can I find ONLY the validation images that are actually user visible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```
if ( $('img.validation:visible').length ) // validation errors exist
{
    alert("errors");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img.validation:visible")
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/visibility-filter-selectors/